# How can I get my smash function to run and return my combined list?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to get through the Sentence Smash Kata on CodeWars, I'm pretty new to coding and I am wondering why my code isn't properly running.
My code

```
def smash(words):
    a  = ['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'great']
    return " ".join(a)
    
smash("")
```

I can't remove the "words" parameter and I think I have to instantiate it but I don't know in what way I should do that. I thought substituting the argument for quotes would work and it did run but none of my tests passed.

Comment: Please be aware that questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. Include in your question the specifications of the code challenge.

Comment: Your function always returns "hello world this is great" and ignores the argument. Your function should not have `a` nor a hard-coded list. Remember that the code challenge site will make the call to your function -- not you. They will pass a list as argument.

Comment: Pass the list into the function, rather than hardcoding it inside the function.

Comment: To remove the words parameter just say `def smash():` and then call it like `smash()`. (but we are not sure what you are trying to do, like tincot said your function is always gonna return the same hello world string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a function, everything within the `(...)` is an argument (or a parameter, there is probably some specific technical distinction, but either is generally fine). Those are variables that are then usable within the scope of the function, and they are set when you call the function with whatever you have in the () when you call.

This framework allows you to make the general function and then do specific things with it based on what you pass in.

In your case, what you probably want is this:

```py
def smash(words):
    return ' '.join(words)

my_words = ['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'great']

smash(my_words)
```

In the scope of the function, you have the variable `words` and you attempt to join the pieces with a `' '` inbetween.

Then, outside the scope of the function, you declare a variable with an actual, concrete list of words, and then call the function using that concrete list.

Comment: I am understanding little by little now, I am looking to fully understand this principal/fundamental, is there any sources or YouTube videos that can help explain this to me better? I understand how the join method works now, I guess where I'm still getting a little bit caught at is how "words" in the function is also being used inside of the function where the join method is being called. Putting it in terms of scopes really helps though, thanks!

Comment: I have generally found www.realpython.com to be a great python resource. They have an article here on defining your own functions - haven't read it specifically, but having skimmed it it is probably useful for you: https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/

Answer (score 0):

`def smash(words)` defines a function that accepts some argument named 'words'.

`smash("")` calls that function and passes an empty string to the words argument.

Try this and see if it helps clear things up:

```
def smash(words):
    return " ".join(words)
    
smash(['hello', 'world', 'this', 'is', 'great'])
```